# How to send MMS with image attachment and some text in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to attach image within some text to MMS in Android.I found a lot here on SO as well as on Google but still not get the right solution yet.My code is as:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("image/png");
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body",
                    getResources().getText(R.string.Message));
            // sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

            Uri mms_uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                    + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.app_logo);

            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mms_uri.toString());

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, ""));
```

Please Help me for my this Issue.

Comment: you are getting any error when running current code?

Comment: no not getting any error but i am not able to attach image that's it.i dont know where i am wrong.Can you give me any suggestions regarding MMS image Attachment?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had any luck with this? I tried a similar approach, and found that

```
Uri mms_uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.app_logo);
```

is not universal. I managed to do it by making a copy of the image file in the assets folder and converting it into a File. You could do something like this:

```
File f = new File(getCacheDir()+"/app_logo.png");
if (!f.exists()) try {
    InputStream is = getAssets().open("R.drawable.app_logo");
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fos.write(buffer);
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }

sharePicture = f.getPath();
```